# QueryString Validation Problem

Tags: c#, query-string

Whenever I access my page directly (mypage.aspx) it returns an error:

> Object not set to object not set to an instance of an object.

If I add a querystring (mypage.aspx?sr=true) it works but I am checking to make sure that before it evaluates that it has a value, and it should not have a value. So why am I getting the error when I access the page directly?

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string qu1 = "";
    string qu2 = "";
    string qu3 = "";

    if (Request.QueryString["qu1"] != null)
    {
        qu1 = Request.QueryString["qu1"].ToString();
        if (qu1 != "")
        {
            qu1DropDownList.SelectedValue = industry;
        }
    }

    if (Request.QueryString["qu2"] != null)
    {
        qu2 = Request.QueryString["qu2"].ToString();
        if (qu2 != "")
        {
            qu2DropDownList.SelectedValue = category;
        }
    }

    fillDropDownList();

    if (Request.QueryString["qu3"] != null)
    {
        qu3 = Request.QueryString["qu3"].ToString();
        if (qu3 != "")
        {
            qu3tDropDownList.SelectedValue = product;
        }
    }
}

string search = "";
string qu1value = IndustryDropDownList.SelectedValue;
string qu2value = ProductCategoryDropDownList.SelectedValue;
string qu3value = ProductDropDownList.SelectedValue;

using (SPSite site = new SPSite("SITE"))
using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = site.OpenWeb())
{
    SPList oList = oWebsiteRoot.Lists["SpacesInfo"];
    SPListItemCollection items = null;

    if (Request.QueryString["sr"] != "" && Request.QueryString["sr"] != null)
    {
        search = Request.QueryString["sr"].ToString();
        if (search == "true")
        {
            if (indvalue == "select" & catvalue == "select")
            {
                items = oList.Items;
            }
            else if (indvalue != "select" & catvalue != "select" & provalue != "select")
            {
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "MYQUERY";
                items = oList.GetItems(query);
            }
            else if (indvalue != "select" & catvalue != "select" & provalue == "select")
            {
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "MYQUERY";
                items = oList.GetItems(query);

            }
            else if (indvalue != "select" & catvalue == "select")
            {
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Industry' /><Value Type='Choice'>" + indvalue +
                    "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                items = oList.GetItems(query);
            }
            else if (indvalue == "select" & catvalue != "select" & provalue == "select")
            {
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "MYQUERY";
                items = oList.GetItems(query);
            }
            else if (indvalue == "select" & catvalue != "select" & provalue != "select")
            {
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "MYQUERY";
                items = oList.GetItems(query);
            }
            else
            {
                errorLabel.Text = "Please contact the administrator.";
                items = oList.Items;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            items = oList.Items;
        }
    }
    DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    table = items.GetDataTable();
    spacerepeater.DataSource = table;
    spacerepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does the exception occur? What line?

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of this if statement:

```
if (Request.QueryString["sr"] != "" && Request.QueryString["sr"] != null)
```

should be

```
if (Request.QueryString["sr"] != null && Request.QueryString["sr"] != "")
```

The issue is this, in your code it looks for the empty string ("") and fails because the object is null.  In my version it will see the value is null and fail out of the if statement without checking the second one.

This is often called short circuit evaluation.

ref http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Or just use `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["sr"]))`

Comment: How would this order cause a problem? Comparing `null` to an empty string will work just fine

Comment: @BrokenGlass as reported by OP it throws an error (it is an lvalue).  Try it yourself.

Comment: @Hogan: Did you try it? The first version does **not** throw an exception and evaluates just fine, your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["sr"]))
{
   //Do stuff
}
```